# Dynamic form fields on lightning record page is not working

Tags: salesforce, page-layout

I am trying to enable lightning dynamic form of case page layout on the lightning record page in my dev sandbox. I don't see any option for the same. However, I have done this previously for the same sandbox for other object. Please advise if I am missing something here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Case is a standard object, we can't enable lightning dynamic forms to show/hide fields conditionally on detail page.

for more info visit:- [https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.dynamic_forms_overview.htm&type=5]

Comment: It's not appropriate to ask users to upvote/accept answers, either within the answer or in a comment.